# Element slides under other elements on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

First, I apologize for my horrible code. I'm working on my first site, and while it displays correctly on desktop, on mobile the float left goes underneath the rest of the site. Here's the code for some of the homepage. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
background: #90EE90; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #90EE90, #00FF00); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #90EE90, #00FF00); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #90EE90, #00FF00); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #90EE90, #00FF00); /* Standard syntax */
}
h1{font-family:Montserrat;color:000000;}
p {font-family:Montserrat;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;color:000000;}
h2 {font-family:'Montserrat', bold;}
h3 {font-family:Montserrat;}
div.member {
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
}
div.desc {
    float: left;
    padding:0px;
</style>
<body>
<div class="member" align="right">
<h2><u>Social Media</u></h2>
<h3><a href="youtube link">Youtube</a></h3>
<h3><a href="facebook link">Facebook</a></h3>
<h3><a href="twitter link">Twitter</a></h3>
<h3><a href="twitch link">Twitch</a></h3>
<h3><a href="instagram link">Instagram</a></h3>
<h2><u>Member Pages</u></h2>
<h3><a href="name1.html">name1</a></h3>
<h3><a href="name2.html">name2</a></h3>
<h3><a href="name3.html">name3</a></h3>
<h3><a href="name4.html">name4</a></h3>
</div>
<div>
<h1><img src="/images/logo.png" alt="Logo" hspace="20" align="left">Group name</h1>
</div>
<div class="desc" style="height: 300px; width: 700px">
<p hspace="15" align="middle">Description of site</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: the align attribute is obsolete as of HTML5 and the hspace attribute has been obsolete since the stone age.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason parts go to the bottom of the page is because they are in a fixed width container that isn't responsive. There ends up being no room where they were so the browser moves them to the bottom.

`px` units are fixed. What you want to use is `%` so that it maintains its width ratio when the window is smaller

Try dividing up your web page into larger containers. In this case I went with a `leftSide` and a `rightSide`. I then gave them a width in `%` that added up to `100%` and then set them to be `float: left` and `float: right` respectively.

If you don't want them to always be set to the same width ratio as this for all screen widths then you'll want to look into [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Some other tips:

- Try not to use inline styling unless you have to
- Similar to the point above, I recommend not using html attributes for things that could be done with CSS. Putting them in CSS makes your code cleaner and easier to read.
- Consider making your list of links on the right side an unordered list `ul` + `li` as it is better suited for that.

```css
body {
  background: #90EE90;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #90EE90, #00FF00);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #90EE90, #00FF00);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #90EE90, #00FF00);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #90EE90, #00FF00);
  /* Standard syntax */
}
h1 {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  color: 000000;
}
p {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: 000000;
}
h2 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', bold;
}
h3 {
  font-family: Montserrat;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.leftSide {
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
}
.rightSide {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
}
.header img {
  float: left;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rightSide">
    <h2><u>Social Media</u></h2>
    <h3><a href="youtube link">Youtube</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="facebook link">Facebook</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="twitter link">Twitter</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="twitch link">Twitch</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="instagram link">Instagram</a></h3>
    <h2><u>Member Pages</u></h2>
    <h3><a href="name1.html">name1</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="name2.html">name2</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="name3.html">name3</a></h3>
    <h3><a href="name4.html">name4</a></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="leftSide">
    <div class="header">
      <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
      <h1>Group name</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p class="center">Description of site</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked great. I also added the unordered lists like you suggested.